# Como importar clases desde otro archivo Python

Tags: python, poo

Quiero importar dos Clases para utilizarlas en un Test del programa

El directorio es este:

**Carpeta principal** POO

(adentro de la carpeta):

Bicicletas.py (aqui estan las clases a importar)

Bicicletas_Test.py (quiero importar las clases aqui)

Lo que hago en *Bicicletas_Test.py* es:

```
from Bicicletas import Alquiler_bicicleta, Cliente
```

Lo que ocurre es que no reconoce esas clases sino que me sale "Unsolved reference '*nombre de la clase*' 
"

Utilizo Pycharm. Disculpen si la pregunta es redundante o repetitiva pero he buscado en todos lados y no he encontrado nada.

Comment: Eso fue error mio, quise poner Bicicletas, sin el .py

Comment: Gracias, revise ese post y pude solucionarlo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes importar el módulo completo de la forma: `from Bicicletas import *`. De igual modo, en el siguiente post mencionan dicho error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm. Espero que te sirva de ayuda